# Find max value from list having single element

Tags: python, list, max

The list contain single element with the array values. How can i find the maximum value from list?
list is  [array([[ 4,  5,  6], [10, 11, 12]])]. Find below code for reference.

```
import numpy
a=np.arange(1,13).reshape(2,2,3)
pt=[np.array([0,1]),np.array([1,1])]
list=[]
list.append(a[pt[0],pt[1]])
```

Comment: Note: `list` is a python builtin. You probably don't want to use it as a variable name. Anyway, to get a maximum value in a numpy array use `np.max`. So `np.max(list[0])` should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max of a numpy array with the [numpy max function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html):

```py
m = np.max(list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

first import numpy as np because of line 2, when you called the numpy module as np.
this is the code that I find a solution for you, there are more elegant answers for sure

```
holder = 0
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        for z in range(len(y)):
            if holder < y[z]:
                holder = y[z]
print(holder)
```